# How can I bind an entity Data Source to the results of a query

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a query that will go away an and find data

```
 Dim HSNs As String = String.Join(",", ListOfHSNs.Cast(Of String)().ToArray())



        Dim query As String = "SELECT VALUE O FROM v_BillData AS O WHERE O.HSNumber IN {'" & HSNs & "'}"



        Dim hs As New ObjectQuery(Of v_BillData)(query, CType(Session("ObjectCon"), ObjectContext))
```

what I now wish to do is to use the results of this query to databind to a EntityDataSource
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the Selecting EntityDataSource event like in the following example:

```
Protected Sub EntityDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EntityDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)
  Dim HSNs As String = String.Join(",", ListOfHSNs.Cast(Of String)().ToArray())
  Dim query As String = "SELECT VALUE O FROM v_BillData AS O WHERE O.HSNumber IN {'" & HSNs & "'}"
  Dim source As EntityDataSource = Nothing
  source = TryCast(Me.Page.FindControl("EntityDataSource1"),EntityDataSource)
  If (Not source Is Nothing) Then
    source.EntitySetName = Nothing
    source.CommandText = query
  End If
End Sub
```

You should set EntitySetName to Nothing because it will throw an error if you have setup EntityDataSource before.

Comment: If using SQL Statement, then why have to use EntityDataSource?

Comment: @SilverNight, this is not SQL, it is Entity SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx . EntityDataSource accepts only Entity SQL queries as data source.

Comment: Thanks for correct my false. But one advantage of using L2S or EF are the strong-type of Data classes generate from SQL Server. When the database table schema is changed, visual studio can be make a compliation warning, and it is easy for trace what should i correct.But using Entity SQL , it doesn't.  however,it really the only way to join table in latest version EF right now.

Comment: @SilverNight, you are correct. However, this particular question deals with a query that selects entire entity object, so the type mismatch errors should not arise.