# Use QueryExtender to Search for Term across Multiple DataFields?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a textbox with button wired up to a queryextender. My goal is that someone might enter into the textbox a name (e.g. "Dave Mackey") and receive back all relevant results. The problem is that this information is spread across two columns in the underlying database (e.g. FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME). My code looks like this:

```
 <asp:QueryExtender ID="QueryExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="EntityDataSource1" >
    <asp:SearchExpression DataFields="first_name,last_name" SearchType="Contains">
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFilterText" />
    </asp:SearchExpression>
</asp:QueryExtender>
```

If I enter "Mackey" it returns results, but "Dave Mackey" returns no results, I'm assuming b/c it is looking for the entire value in one first (either, but not both together), whereas I want it to return any rows where it finds the entirety even if it is spread across multiple DataFields. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption.
[QueryExtender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.queryextender.aspx)'s SearchExpression performs the search using the entire txtFilterText in each field in the DataFields enumeration.
What about using [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and [specifying a custom query in the EntityDataSoure OnSelecting event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901142/how-can-i-bind-an-entity-data-source-to-the-results-of-a-query)?